# Use Form Buttons For jqGrid Edit Functions

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

Using jqGrid  5.0.1, I have a functioning grid in an asp.net webforms project written in C#.  The edit functions are controlled via the buttons in the navigation bar of the grid.  To make the page conform to the other pages in the projects, I'd like to call the editing functions from buttons on the form - separate from the jqGrid.  I've not found a whole lot on SO concerning this, but one topic covered the add row function.  So I implemented the code and when I click the button, the edit form appears for a split second then goes away.

I am really stumped on this.  I've looked at the documentation and tried lots of combinations, but have yet to get this working, and I have not even started on the edit and delete functions - and on the delete, a I need to send additional information in the post data to my edit url.  My grid code is below, including the commented out nav button edits.  Is anyone else doing this?

```
        $(function () {
        $('#statusGrid').jqGrid({
            url: 'Handler2.ashx?id=' + id.toString(), 
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',

            colNames: ['ProjNum', 'Status', 'Status Date', 'Status Time', 'User ID', 'Memo Text', 'Memo Number', 'Status Number'],
            colModel: [
                        { name: 'ProjNum', index: 'ProjNum', hidden: true, editable: true, editoptions: { defaultValue: $('#tbxProjNum').val() } },
                        { name: "Status", width: 155,
                            editable: true, edittype: "select",
                            editoptions: {
                                dataUrl: "Handler3.ashx",
                                buildSelect: function (data) {
                                    data = $.parseJSON(data);
                                    var select = '<select>', i, l = data.length, item;
                                    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                                        item = data[i];
                                        //select += '<option value="' + item.value + '">' + item.name + '</option>';
                                        select += '<option>' + item.name + '</option>';
                                    }
                                    return select + '</select>';
                                }
                            } },
                        { name: 'Status Date', index: 'Status Date', width: 90, editrules: { required: true }, editable: true, editoptions: { dataInit: function (elem) { $(elem).datepicker({changeYear: true, changeMonth: true}); } } },
                        { name: 'Status Time', index: 'Status Time', width: 90, editrules: { required: true }, editable: true, editoptions: { dataInit: function (elem) { $(elem).timepicker({ timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss' }); } } },
                        { name: 'User ID', index: 'User ID', width: 90, editrules: { required: true }, editable: true },
                        { name: 'Memo Text', index: 'Memo Text', hidden: true, editrules: { required: true, edithidden: true }, editable: true, edittype: 'textarea', editoptions: { rows: "10", cols: "30", defaultValue: "" } },
                        { name: 'Memo Number', index: 'Memo Number', editable: true, hidden: true },
                        { name: 'Status Number', index: 'Status Number', editable: true, hidden: true }
            ],
            //loadonce: true,
            scrollOffset:0,
            //autowidth: true,
            height: "260",
            onSelectRow: function (rowId) {
                var grid = $('#statusGrid');
                $('#tbxStsDesc').val(grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowId, 'Memo Text'));
            },
            pager: '#pager',
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30, "10000:All"],
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            autoencode: true,
            loadComplete: function () {
                $('#statusGrid').setSelection(1);
                $('#tbxStsDesc').val($('#statusGrid').jqGrid('getCell', 1, 'Memo Text'));
            },
            caption: 'Status Detail',
            editurl: 'Handler4.ashx', 
        });

        jQuery("#statusGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false });

        //jQuery("#statusGrid").navGrid("#pagingGrid", {
        //    edit: true,
        //    add: true,
        //    del: true,
        //    save: true,
        //    cancel: true,
        //    search: false,
        //    refresh: false
        //},
        //{
        //    closeAfterEdit: true,
        //    reloadAfterSubmit: true
        //},
        //{
        //    closeAfterAdd: true,
        //    reloadAfterSubmit: true
        //},
        //{
        //    onclickSubmit: function (options, delId) {
        //        return {
        //            memNum: $(this).jqGrid('getCell', delId, 'Memo Number'),
        //            stsNum: $(this).jqGrid('getCell', delId, 'Status Number'),
        //            prjNum: $(this).jqGrid('getCell', delId, 'ProjNum')
        //        };
        //    }
        //});

        $("#btnAdd").on("click", function () {
            $("#statusGrid").editGridRow("new"); 
        });

    })

    var grid = jQuery("#statusGrid"),
    ids = grid.jqGrid("getDataIDs");
    if (ids && ids.length > 0)
    grid.jqGrid("setSelection", ids[0]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seemed to be my use of the asp button on the form.  Clicking it just reloaded the page, no matter what properties I tried.

Replacing these buttons with simple html buttons solved the issue:

```
<input type="button" class="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add Status" />
```

instead of this:

```
<asp:Button class="button" ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add Status" />
```